# What are the auto-created tables by Axon for?

Tags: axon

Before the tables pop up, I first added an `@EventHandler` annotated method in a Spring Component like below:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
@ProcessingGroup("member-info")
public class MemberProjector {

    private final MemberRepo repo;

    @EventHandler
    public void handle(CreatedPaymentEvent evt){
      // TODO : user valid
    }
    // ...
}
```

When I ran the application I got the following exceptions:

```
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.axonframework.spring.config.AxonConfiguration'; nested exception is org.axonframework.lifecycle.LifecycleHandlerInvocationException: One of the start handlers in phase [null] failed with the following exception:
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
            at com.payment.PaymentApplication.main(PaymentApplication.java:9) ~[main/:na]
    Caused by: org.axonframework.lifecycle.LifecycleHandlerInvocationException: One of the start handlers in phase [null] failed with the following exception:
            at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.lambda$invokeStartHandlers$35(DefaultConfigurer.java:693) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.invokeLifecycleHandlers(DefaultConfigurer.java:744) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.invokeStartHandlers(DefaultConfigurer.java:687) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer$ConfigurationImpl.start(DefaultConfigurer.java:811) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.spring.config.AxonConfiguration.start(AxonConfiguration.java:199) ~[axon-spring-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            ... 14 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.axonframework.lifecycle.LifecycleHandlerInvocationException: Failed during invocation of lifecycle handler [public void org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.EventProcessorControlService.start()] on component [org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.EventProcessorControlService@24ea71d]
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2093) ~[na:na]
            at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.invokeLifecycleHandlers(DefaultConfigurer.java:742) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            ... 18 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.axonframework.lifecycle.LifecycleHandlerInvocationException: Failed during invocation of lifecycle handler [public void org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.EventProcessorControlService.start()] on component [org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.EventProcessorControlService@24ea71d]
            at org.axonframework.config.LifecycleHandlerInspector.invokeAndReturn(LifecycleHandlerInspector.java:128) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.config.LifecycleHandlerInspector.lambda$null$0(LifecycleHandlerInspector.java:91) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:558) ~[na:na]
            at org.axonframework.config.DefaultConfigurer.invokeLifecycleHandlers(DefaultConfigurer.java:740) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            ... 18 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
            at org.axonframework.config.LifecycleHandlerInspector.invokeAndReturn(LifecycleHandlerInspector.java:121) ~[axon-configuration-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            ... 27 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.UnableToRetrieveIdentifierException: Exception occurred while trying to establish storage identifier
            at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.retrieveStorageIdentifier(JpaTokenStore.java:265) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.lambda$calculateIdentifier$4(TrackingEventProcessor.java:245) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.common.transaction.TransactionManager.fetchInTransaction(TransactionManager.java:70) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.calculateIdentifier(TrackingEventProcessor.java:244) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.lambda$getTokenStoreIdentifier$3(TrackingEventProcessor.java:240) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]        
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.updateAndGet(AtomicReference.java:209) ~[na:na]
            at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.getTokenStoreIdentifier(TrackingEventProcessor.java:240) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.StreamingEventProcessorInfoMessage.describe(StreamingEventProcessorInfoMessage.java:58) ~[axon-server-connector-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.EventProcessorControlService.lambda$infoSupplier$1(EventProcessorControlService.java:115) ~[axon-server-connector-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.impl.ControlChannelImpl.lambda$sendScheduledProcessorInfo$3(ControlChannelImpl.java:245) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValuesView.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:4772) ~[na:na]
            at io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.impl.ControlChannelImpl.sendScheduledProcessorInfo(ControlChannelImpl.java:245) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]       
            at io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.impl.ControlChannelImpl.registerEventProcessor(ControlChannelImpl.java:226) ~[axonserver-connector-java-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
            at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.EventProcessorControlService.lambda$start$0(EventProcessorControlService.java:105) ~[axon-server-connector-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1338) ~[na:na]
            at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.processor.EventProcessorControlService.start(EventProcessorControlService.java:103) ~[axon-server-connector-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            ... 32 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
            at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3357) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3294) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.getConfig(JpaTokenStore.java:272) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            at org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.jpa.JpaTokenStore.retrieveStorageIdentifier(JpaTokenStore.java:263) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
            ... 47 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]     
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]    
            at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4437) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4427) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]       
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:544) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1186) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2779) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2723) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3322) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            ... 56 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TOKEN_ENTRY" not found; SQL statement:
    select tokenentry0_.processor_name as processo1_3_0_, tokenentry0_.segment as segment2_3_0_, tokenentry0_.owner as owner3_3_0_, tokenentry0_.timestamp as timestam4_3_0_, tokenentry0_.token as token5_3_0_, tokenentry0_.token_type as token_ty6_3_0_ from token_entry tokenentry0_ where tokenentry0_.processor_name=? and tokenentry0_.segment=? [42102-200]
            at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
            ... 78 common frames omitted
```

Lastly, this is my `application.yml`:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8282

spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      settings:
        trace : true
  output.ansi.enabled: always
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/delivery/payment
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    sql:
      init :
        mode : always
        data-locations : classpath:data.sql
        schema-locations : classpath:schema.sql
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    generate-ddl: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  application:
    name: payment-service
```

In those error messages I found:
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TOKEN_ENTRY" not found`

So I tried to create that table and I've been trying this and that, tables were created automatically. But I don't know why these tables are auto-created yet.

[image]

// Member is just my entity

Is it normal for a table like this to be created in the h2-DB?
I'm a beginner at Axon and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Those are axon internal tables to keep track of the state of the events/sagas what not. The Axon javadocs and manual are your friends: https://apidocs.axoniq.io/4.5/org/axonframework/eventhandling/tokenstore/jpa/JpaTokenStore.html (this is linked to the token entry table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tables are auto-created because you are using Axon's Spring Boot Starter in combination with a storage solution. Axon's auto-configuration spots the fact you have persistent storage and thus expects you want to have the default entities axon requires.

Let me list what they are for:

- `SAGA_ENTRY` - Stores the serialized sagas. Read more on Sagas [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/sagas).
- `ASSOCIATION_VALUE_ENTRY` - Stores the associations from event identifiers to saga identifiers. Hence, it is the lookup table for Axon to associate your events with your sagas.
- `TOKEN_ENTRY` - Stores the serialized `TrackingToken` instances your `StreamingEventProcessors` use for handling events. In short, these tokens keep track of the progress through the event stream. Read more on Streaming Processors and Tracking Tokens [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming).

> Is it normal for a table like this to be created in the h2-DB?

When using Axon's Spring Auto Configuration, then yes, it is. Axon expects you need all of them, so it is created upfront.

> I'm a beginner at Axon, and I don't know where to start.

[enter link description here](https://axoniq.io/event-overview/implementing-event-driven-systems-using-ddd-cqrs-and-event-sourcing---training-august-2021)You should know that there is an Axon training you can follow (as found here). Either attend one of the live sessions you can find here or go for the [AxonIQ Academy](https://academy.axoniq.io/).

Comment: Sure thing YongD!